# how to get values of field form class object nested in another clas

Tags: c#, list, class, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

```
public void Fill()
    {
        List<testowa1> lista = new List<testowa1>();
        var item = new testowa1()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Nazwa = "Pierwszy",
            Cena = new testowa2()
            {
                Cena = 32.22M
            }
        };
        lista.Add(item);
        lista.Add(item);
        lista.Add(item);
        lista.Add(item);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = lista;
    }

    public class testowa1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nazwa { get; set; }
        public testowa2 Cena { get; set; }
    }
    public class testowa2
    {
        public decimal Cena { get; set; }
    }
```

that is result:
[image: result of program]

So, how i can get value of testowa2.Cena into data grid ?
I don't know what to do. I was looking in google but nothing found

Comment: can you try that: write `dataGridView1.DataBind();` after `dataGridView1.DataSource = lista;`

Comment: @MustafaÇil it's not working becouse is winforms not web and datagridview hasn't DataBind() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand your question completely.

Do you want something like that;

```
var cenaValues = dataGridView1.DataSource.Items.Where(x => x.Cena != null)
.Select(x => x.Cena.Cena).ToList();
```

Comment: @FrycuBOP How does this have to do with your problem of the values not displaying correctly? "how i can get value of testowa2.Cena into data grid ?" This is just getting the values **from** the DataGridView, not **into**.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad dataGridView1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource = lista.Select(x=>new { x.ID, x.Nazwa, x.Cena.Cena }).ToList(); just like this.

Comment: @FrycuBOP I guess that works, but that's a round-about way of fixing it. My solution is cleaner (unless you can't change testowa1) and takes advantage of data binding so that the datagridview is updated if the object's values change.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad that's the point i cant change class, I allways can run this method after update list

Comment: @FrycuBOP Another option is to have that same decimal property and then just hide the testowa2 column since it shows it as a string instead of the decimal. That way you still get the data binding but don't require changing the testowa2 property.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to testowa1 to expose the decimal property kept in testowa2. This will put that value into the DataGridview, but you'll still need to hide the extra column that shows testowa2 as a string.

I believe this works because Data Binding can only go one level deep in an object's properties. In your code, instead of displaying the testowa2's decimal value it would just show the string equivalent of testowa2 because it doesn't drill down into testowa2 to get the decimal value. Disclaimer: I don't actually understand data binding well and I couldn't find anything to back up my explanation. So this could be wrong, but my changes to your code do work.

```
public class testowa1
{
    public decimal CenaValue
    {
        get { return Cena.Cena; }
        set { Cena.Cena = value; }
    }
}

// in Fill
var item = new testowa1()
{
    ID = 1,
    Nazwa = "Pierwszy",
    Cena = new testowa2(),
    CenaValue = 32.22M
};

// after you added the list as the datasource
dataGridView1.Columns["Cena"].Visible = false;
```